# Bash scripting - if cases $? > 0

Tags: bash, scripting, rhel, if-case

Sorry for possible spam, I'm finishing RHEL Security Hardening/Auditing script, where I want an overall result in the end.
For example,

```
# PermitEmptyPasswords
grep -E '^\s*PermitEmptyPasswords\s+no\s*' /etc/ssh/sshd_config &> /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ];
then echo "[ OK ] PermitEmptyPasswords is properly configured";
else echo "[ ERROR ] PermitEmptyPasswords is not properly configured";
fi
```

Now, my idea for overall result (Safe/Not safe) is to make sum of all these if $? cases, if all cases give sum of 0, it will echo "This system is properly configured by hardening policy", else echo "This system has errors" + reprint all errors where $? is > 0.

How to get this work? I'm new at scripting, so any help will be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you have an error message?

Comment: I don't have any error messages. I need an example how to sum all if [ $? = 0 ]; cases from all of my modules and print a message when the sum of all if [ $? = 0 ]; are 0, and another message for any > 0

Comment: @Kristian: `$?` is generated for every shell command run and bash does not store the history of exit codes of all the previous commands, just the last command's value is known in `$?`. Explain your requirement more, I am sure there is a better way to do what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: http://www.pics.rs/i/M64xQ - on this screenshot I've put some explanation. To simplify it, all OK's > in the end I must have a message "All marks are OK", if there's a single error in one of the sections, another message in the end will be shown: Fix errors: 1/3/5 etc.

Comment: Personally, btw, rather than a sum I tend to use a bitmask in similar cases. `foo; (( retval |= $? ))` ORs the bits of `$?` from command `foo` in with what you already have in the variable `retval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is:

create an empty variable and give it a value of 0

```
count=0
```

Increment it by 1 every time you have an exit status bigger than 0. Example:

```
if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]; then ((count++)); fi
```

To print it all out at the end, you can do a simple array, but I think just appending the content to a file, and then reading at the end should suffice.

```
if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]; then ((count++)) && echo "whatever" >>filename; fi
```

At the end, just cat the filename and to show to the number of errors, just echo the count variable:

```
echo "Count number: $count"
```

P.S use double opening and closing brackets if you are using bash as your shell.

Comment: Does it work for if [  $? = 0 ]; also or it must be [[ $? - gt 0 ]]; because I don't understand really what -gt 0 variable does.

Comment: for comparing integers, it is not recommended to use "==". 
-gt 0 in this case means: Greater than 0.

Comment: If you're going to use bashisms, might make it `(( $? > 0 ))`. That said, it's generally better to branch directly on your command's exit status where possible. `foo || ((++count))` will do the job much more tersely with no `$?` in sight.

Comment: And note `++count` vs `count++` -- that difference can be important if folks use `set -e`; see the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Answer (score 2):

@py9 has already answered the question, but I'd like to point something else out: when testing whether a command succeeded, it's simpler and somewhat more robust to use the command directly as the `if` condition, rather than using `$?` to check its exit status afterward. Also, rather than redirecting `grep`'s output to /dev/null, you can use `grep -q` (quiet mode). Finally (as @CharlesDuffy pointed out), `grep -E` understands extended regular expression syntax, which doesn't include `\s` (that's part of PCRE -- perl-compatible regular expression -- syntax). So use something like this:

```
if grep -q -E '^[[:space:]]*PermitEmptyPasswords[[:space:]]+no[[:space:]]*' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; then
    echo "[ OK ] PermitEmptyPasswords is properly configured"
else
    echo "[ ERROR ] PermitEmptyPasswords is not properly configured"
    ((count++))
fi
```

Comment: `grep -E` doesn't guarantee support of `\s`, which is not ERE but PCRE. Consider `[[:space:]]` instead. Otherwise, though, this is an important and well-made point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good catch; I didn't even look at the RE. Fixed now.